# CakePHP 3 best way to add additional data to url

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I wanted to ask, about strategy, how can i archive this:

I have url: www.mydomain.com/pages

Now, if some if clausure will return true, i want attach this param to all urls:

www.mydomain.com/pages?id=swa or
www.mydomain.com?id=swa

I have no idea how to start,
Thank You for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet would probably be to use a URL filter, it will affect all URLs that are being generated using the core helpers or the `Router` class, as long as they are being passed as [**routing arrays**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/glossary.html#term-routing-array), ie

```
['controller' => 'abc', 'action' => 'xyz', /* ... */]
```

URLs passed as strings, like `/abc/xyz` will *not* be affected!

```
\Cake\Routing\Router::addUrlFilter(function ($params, $request) {
    $key = 'id';
    $value = 'swa';

    if (!array_key_exists($key, $params)) {
        $params[$key] = $value;
    }

    return $params;
});
```

This would add the parameter to all URLs (unless they already have that parameter set). But be careful, in case there is a matching connected route that defines a route element with the same name, it will steal the parameter and use it for the element instead of adding it to the query string!

Also note that this will only affect form actions that do explicitly define an action URL, if you'd wanted it to affect the ones that pick up the current URL too, then you'd also have to modify `$request->query`

```
$request->query[$key] = $value;
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Routing > Creating Persistent URL Parameters](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#creating-persistent-url-parameters)**
- **[API > \Core\Routing\Router::addUrlFilter()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Routing.Router.html#_addUrlFilter)**

Comment: Great function, didn't know abot that. It helps. Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a one off you can do that using redirects

```
return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display', $pageId]);
```

or via html helper

```
echo $this->Html->link(
    'Page 1',
    ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display', 1]
);
```